# undefined local variable or method in ROR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having problems showing photos in the `views/products/show.html.erb`. I always get this error:

> undefined local variable or method 'product' for
>   <#:0x007fe0bc949fb8> 
>   Did you mean? `@product`

This is the code I'm using to show the photos in the view:

`views/products/show.html.erb`

```
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 center-block" >
       <% product.images.each do |image_product| %>
        <%= image_tag image_product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive" %>
       <% end %>
   </div>
```

here is the `show`method for the `products_controller.rb` as it is after I added `@products` to it, after I had the error messages.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


      def show
      @products = Product.all

      end


    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :price_usd, :image, :category_id, :stock_quantity, :label_id, :query, :slug, images_attributes: [:image , :id , :_destroy])
    end


 end
```

here is the `product.rb` model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   acts_as_list :scope => [:category, :label]
   belongs_to :category
   belongs_to :label

   has_many :images
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
   has_many :product_items, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

and here is the `image.rb`model

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "500x500#", thumb: "100x100#" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, can someone please advise?

Comment: Are you using any before callback to set some variable in the show method? Can you add the whole controller?

Comment: Yes @SebastiánPalma please see the controller I added,  I´m using `before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]`  How is that affecting this? what to do?

Comment: What do you want for a show method, to get all the records? or just an specific one?, in such case you could remove the `@products` variable and then try to iterate over the images from `@product` that comes from the `set_product` method, like `@product.images.each ...`

Comment: I would like to see  all pictures for the product shown in the `show.html.erb` The plan is to use some kind of a `Carrousel` to show them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different variables in your show method, but you're not using any of them, as you're doing `product.images`, that means a local variable in somewhere, if you want to get the images from an specific record, you can use the `@product` variable setted in your private method `set_product`, and to remove `@products = Product.all` if you don't need it.

Try with something like:

```
<% @product.images.each do |image_product| %>
  <%= image_tag image_product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: that did the trick, don´t know why I didn't figure it out my self :)

Answer (score 2):

Use instance variable **@product** instead of **product**

**product** is a local variable hence can not be used in the show file until explicitly shared as local variable.